# Need Regular Expression logic to find string

Tags: c#

I want to find a particular string (word) from a sentence.

Given string:

> "In a given health plan your Plan Name: Medical and Plan Type: PPO whose effective date: 2019-01-01 and coverage value $100 and $200".

1. if I pass `"Plan Name:"` then my output would be `"Medical"`.
2. if I pass `"Plan Type:"` then my output would be `"PPO"`.
3. if I pass `"effective date:"` then my output would be `"2019-01-01"`.
4. if I pass `"coverage value"` then in this case I need two value.
   Min value `"$100"` and MAX value `"$200"`.

Similarly I need email address from a given sentence. There could be scenario where I just need to pic a date, email or a numeric value from a given sentence. In this case I do not have any previous value to match.

I need a regular expression logic that covers all above requirements.

Comment: OK, so where is the Problem? Are those Inputstrings always the same lenght/structure? What did you try? However: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8 <- Here is all you need to know. Or do you need someone to write code for you? Then you should probabbly check out a site to hire Freelancers.

Comment: Basically a brunch of [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) one after an other. And one substring. boils down to : Is the text in the string? After the index + length string where is the next space? And the next space after that? I want the string between those 2 spaces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service

Comment: For the _"Similarly I need email address from a given sentence."_, it make no sense there is email in the sentense and email are not simple. check the rfc for email be ready to get your mind blow.

Comment: _"There could be scenario where I just need to pic a date, email or a numeric value from a given sentence."_, Make even less sense. More that those incredible complexe email regex you also want to be able to find a date and a numeric value? How many culture and format and exception does that allow?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication118
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "In a given health plan your Plan Name: Medical and Plan Type: PPO whose effective date: 2019-01-01 and coverage value $100 and $200";
            string pattern = @"(?'key'\w+):\s+(?'value'[-\d\w]+)|(?'key'\w+)\s+(?'value'\$\d+\s+and\s+\$\d+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```